# There is something wrong when i install a package named "scater" in R

Tags: r, macos, bioinformatics

I'm tring to learn the workflow in scRNAseq, and a package named "scater" was requied.
"densvis" is a dependency.

This is what happened at the end of the installation.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [densvis.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘densvis’
```

and i'm using a macbook pro with M1 chip.

I followed the steps described on this website
https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/

but it didn't work. i don't know whether i do this in a right way.

Comment: does https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/ help?

Comment: Does Bioconductor build for Apple Silicon? It hadn’t the last I checked - we had students install the osx-64 version of R, which will run in emulation (Rosetta).

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to install gfortran on Mac with homebrew. By default, this should go to /opt which addresses the missing libraries warning as mentioned above.

```
brew install gfortran
```